# Filter Django Admin user list according to logged in user

Tags: python, django

So I'm building a school management system in Django Admin. There are multiple institutions of that school and we want to build admins that can only manipulate data of students, teachers, etc. of that certain institute. Eg: if the admin user is of ABC institute, he/she should only able to edit data of ABC students, teachers, etc.

Here is my custom user and institute model:

```
class Institute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Our own User model. Made by overriding Django's own AbstractUser model.
    We need to define this as the main user model in settings.py with 
    variable AUTH_USER_MODEL *IMPORTANT* 
    """
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name="email address"
    )
    institute = models.ForeignKey(
        Institute, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Every institute has a domain principal:

```
class DomainPrincipal(User):
    is_admin = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

    # Control model features
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Domain Principal'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Domain Principals'
```

I created the following custom admin to show only domain principals belonging to the institute the current admin user belongs to:

```
@admin.register(UserPrincipal)
class DomainPrincipalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'institute')

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(DomainPrincipalAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(
            institute=request.user.institute
        )
```

But it's not working. It's still showing me the complete list.

Comment: What Django version do you use? In Django > 1.5 method should be called `get_queryset`

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a shot.

Comment: get_queryset will do the same by default, you need to override that.

Comment: is there model `UserPrincipal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:** 
filter using institution name
Without changing much of your code:

override **get_queryset** , 
something like, (not tested, please consider it as psuedo-code)

```
class DomainPrincipalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user:
            current_instituition_name = user.instituition_name
            qs = qs.filter(institute = current_instituition_name)
        return qs
```

**Solution 2:** DB separation

Keep separate DB per-institute and do *[DB routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/)*

**Solution 3:** Group separation

Create groups-per-instituition and add users to groups during registration (user creation phase)